# Closed end funds via Eikon API

Tags: thomson-reuters-eikon, refinitiv-eikon-api, refinitiv-eikon

im trying to pull some data for closed-end funds via Eikon. I´m trying to get the fund price and the discount but I don't know the right column_fields name. Anybody got any ideas?

```
column_fields = [
            " TR.FundNAV.Date",         
                 "TR.FundNAV", 
                 "TR.FundMid"]

def get_nav_data(lipper_ids, start_date,end_date ):
    for value in df2['Lipper RIC']:
    
        data, err = ek.get_data(value, fields = column_fields, 
                                parameters= {
                                    'SDate':start_date, 
                                    'EDate':end_date,
                                "Frq": "D"
                                },
                            )
    
        filepath = os.path.join("D:" , f"{value}.xlsx" )
        data.to_excel(filepath, index= False)
        data_frames[f'data_{value}'] = data
        print(data)
    return(data)
```

I tried "TR.PriceFund" but its not working